# Remastersys and Hostname

Tags: 12.04, remastersys

An unsuccessful installation attempt of Remastersys installation changed my ubuntu 12.04 precise desktop hostname.

Am unable to revert to my original hostname of my desktop. Changing `/etc/hostname` ; `/etc/hosts` ; `sysctl kernel.hostname` and restarting the services did not help.

After reboot something rewrite my hostname to "custom".

Appreciate all your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname):

> The host name is usually set once at system startup in /etc/rc.d/rc.inet1 or /etc/init.d/boot (normally by reading the contents of a file which contains the host name, e.g. /etc/hostname).

So you only have to set it in /etc/hostname